# Scheme function doesn't return value

Tags: function, scheme

Here is what the function should do:

I am giving it list of "pairs" that look like (((a . b) . c) ((a . b) . c) ((a. b) . c) ...)
where:

a means if the vertex is visited 1 for yes 0 for no

b means what is the value of the shortest path to the vertex so far (if it is -1 it is infinity)

c is the number of the parent (if it has so far if it doesn't it is the number of the pair if you count the first pair for 1 second for 2 and etc.)

The function should return the number of the next unvisited pair (vertex) with the lowest cost of the path so far. 
 Example:
(((0 . 10) . 1) ((0 . 4) . 2) ((1 . 3) . 5) ...) here it should return the number 2.

Here is the code

```
(define (chooseNextLowest pairs num retV pointer)
  (if (null? pairs)
      retV
      (if (checkIfPairVis (caar pairs)) 
          (chooseNextLowest (cdr pairs) num retV (+ 1 pointer))
          (if (= -1 num) 
              (chooseNextLowest (cdr pairs) (cdaar pairs) pointer (+ 1 pointer))
              (if (not (= -1 (cdaar pairs)))
                  (if (< (cdaar pairs) num) 
                      (chooseNextLowest (cdr pairs) (cdaar pairs) pointer (+ 1 pointer))
                      (chooseNextLowest (cdr pairs) num retV (+ 1 pointer))))))))
```

I have used some function that are predefined but I think it's clear by their names what they do. 
I call it with num = -1 , retV = -1 and pointer = 1, since I use -1 for infinity and I am sure retV will be changed at least 1 time because everytime I call this function will be at least 1 unvisited pair.

They work fine also this function seems to work fine when I use it with some testPairs but when I use pairs that are returned from other function (since I have to choose everytime the lowest cost unvisited vertex after I update the information in the pairs) it doesnt return any value.

Maybe you will ask to see the other function too but I can't give it at the moment since if I give it I have to give the whole sorce code to make sense so I hope the mistake is somewhere here but I can't find it.

The other function return normal pairs in the type I want them ((a . b ) . c) and etc.

Thank you very much. I am sure I didn't make some things clear so If you have questions feel free to ask me.

Comment: Please make an effort to format properly. Lisp dialects in particular are next to unreadable if not indented perfectly. Break up long lines, and make sure that every brace is an indent; keep indents consistent; for `if`, have condition, then and else each on separate lines.

Comment: I think it might be better if you use cond here, also as @Amadan said please format you're code to make it more readable.

Comment: Thank you guys. I am really new to scheme. Thanks for the advice and I will really try to do it like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After formatting the code it's obvious that in the second deepest `if` you are lacking a alternative. `if` without alternative is very new in Scheme but:

```
(if #f 'true) ;; ==> #undefined
```

Looking at your code, specially `checkIfPairVis` it seems you do `caar` and that's ok for the object, but not for the list with an object. The best way to eliminate such things would be to make accessors in your code which also will make your code easier to read:

```
(define (choose-next-lowest pairs num ret-v pointer)
  ;; accessor based on object
  (define vertex-visited caar)
  (define vertex-shortest cdar)
  (define vertex-parents cdr)

  (if (null? pairs)
      ret-v
      (let ((obj (car pairs)))
        (cond 
          ((check-if-pair-vis (vertex-visited obj))
           (choose-next-lowest (cdr pairs) num ret-v (+ 1 pointer)))
          ...))))
```

After fixing that accessor I get 2 as you predicted.
It could be other things wrong of course. Seems to me you need to debug. In DrRacket IDE you could step through your code to ensure it works as designed.

PS: A named let will add accumulators and variables you don't need to expose:

```
(define (choose-next-lowest pairs)
  (define vertex-visited caar)
  (define vertex-shortest cdar)
  (define vertex-parents cdr)
  (define (vertex-visited? v)
    (= 1 (vertex-visited v)))

  (let rec ((pairs pairs) (num -1) (ret-v -1) (pointer 1))
    (if (null? pairs)
        ret-v
        (let ((obj (car pairs)))
          (cond 
            ((vertex-visited? obj) (rec (cdr pairs) num ret-v (+ 1 pointer)))            
            ((= -1 num) (rec (cdr pairs) (vertex-shortest obj) pointer (+ 1 pointer)))            
            ((= -1 (vertex-shortest obj)) 'undefined) ;; something wrong here?            
            ((< (vertex-shortest obj) num) (rec (cdr pairs) (vertex-shortest obj) pointer (+ 1 pointer)))
            (else (rec (cdr pairs) num ret-v (+ 1 pointer))))))))


(choose-next-lowest '(((0 . 10) . 1) ((0 . 4) . 2) ((1 . 3) . 5))) ; ==> 2
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I really can't use DrRacket's debugger and I cant find any tutorial about it. I really would love if I am able to check for logical mistakes but I can't use it properly. Thanks for the rec advice I will take it in mind for sure.

Comment: @user3129475 have you tried [the documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/drracket/debugger.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Your conditional at `(if (not (= -1 (cdaar pairs))) ...` only has a consequent clause.  Without an alternate clause the return of `if` is undefined (officially).  Specifically:

```
      (if (not (= -1 (cdaar pairs)))
          (if (< (cdaar pairs) num) 
              (chooseNextLowest (cdr pairs) (cdaar pairs) pointer (+ 1 pointer))
              (chooseNextLowest (cdr pairs) num retV (+ 1 pointer)))
           <something here>)))))
```

Illustrating how `if` has an undefined return:

```
> (if #f 'yes 'no)
no
> (if #f 'yes)
>                      ; <= nothing printed as a return, just a prompt displayed.
```

Comment: In many Scheme implementations, the "undefined" value is a void value, and is a (usually singleton) object distinct from other objects. It's not "nothing returned", it's just a value that the REPL is programmed not to display. Try `(define foo (list (if #f #f)))` and play around with `foo`, `(car foo)`, etc.

Comment: Yes, exactly.  It is undefined in the standard; implementations define one, recognize it, and skip printing it.  Updated comment for clarity.

Comment: If this answers your question, please consider marking it as an answer and up-voting it when you can.